# ghostscript option to make a pdf with flattened images

Tags: ghostscript

Is there an option to print a pdf in ghostscript as images?

I can use:

`gs  -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pngalpha -r300 -sOutputFile=p%03d.png my.pdf`

Then use imagemagick to make a pdf out of them with:

`convert *.png new.pdf`

PDF printers seem to have an option that does the same thing that is a checkbox that says "print as image".  I could not find anything in the ghostscript docs that sounded like that was an option.  There may be a term for it that I just don't know to look for.

It is kind of hard to explain why you would want to take a pdf document that is text and turn it into a document of images of text that is 4 times the size of the original but that is what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the only way to do that would be to start with a PDF which contains transparency operations, and select a CompatibilityLevel of 1.3 or less.

I have an idea to implement this feature, but I have not had time to work on it.

You can do it as a 2-pass approach using Ghostscript to render an image, then using the view* scripts to read the image back into Ghostscript and produce a PDF. No better than using convert of course.